# Scala domain modeling with upper type bounds

Tags: scala, oop, domain-driven-design

Is this a sensible use of upper type bounds? I want a Team of different Employees, or a team of just one of the subtypes. Are there drawbacks to modeling it in this way?

```
sealed abstract class Employee {def salary: Double}
object Employee {
  case class IndividualContributor(salary: Double, linesOfCode: Int) extends Employee
  case class Manager(salary: Double, reports: List[Employee]) extends Employee
}
case class Team[T <: Employee](name: String, members: List[T])
```

My rationale is that I may have places where I use a team of any types of Employees, and other places where I need a specific type of Employee:

```
def teamSalaries(team: Team[Employee]) = team.members.map(_.salary).sum
def teamLinesOfCode(team: Team[IndividualContributor]) = team.members.map(_.linesOfCode).sum
```

Comment: I'll update the description

Comment: Yeah that seems like a valid use case, does it work? or do you have any problems with the code?

Comment: No problems, more of a best practice / design question. The same way I might not have problems with inheritance at first, but then later discover a way in which composition would have been a more flexible approach, this is a bit open-ended to understand if there's a different pattern for this that would be better.

Comment: Without more context is hard to tell. This seems like a valid use case for **type bounds**, but you may also use an **ADT** or **Typeclasses** to achieve the same things. But, given your two examples, I would say **type bounds** is the simplest solution. BTW, I would make `Team` _covariant_.

Comment: Thank you! Would love to know how to model this example with ADTs more correctly, since that's what I was attempting to do - the model containing data only, Employee as a sum type - IndividualContributor _or_ Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just for complementing these are other ways to model the same... but, spoiler, I still think that the type bound is still the best solution in this case.

### Normal overloading

```
final case class Team[+T](name: String, members: List[T])

def teamSalaries(team: Team[Employee]): Double = ???
def teamLinesOfCode(team: Team[IndividualContributor]): Double = ???
```

However, this allows creating teams of things that are not employees which is nonsense and IMHO, the idea *(the joke)* of using a statically typed language is to let the compiler catch those errors for you.

### Implicit evidence

```
final case class Team[T](name: String, members: List[T])

def teamSalaries[T](team: Team[T])(implicit ev: T <:< Employee): Double = ???
def teamLinesOfCode[T](team: Team[T])(implicit ev: T <:< IndividualContributor): Double = ???
```

In this case, this is the same as the previous one. But, sometimes this is the only / best way to model something *(see @Dmytro's answer for an example of such case)*.

### And ADT

```
sealed trait Employee {
  def salary: Double
}
object Employee {
  final case class IndividualContributor(salary: Double, linesOfCode: Int) extends Employee
  final case class Manager(salary: Double, reports: List[Employee]) extends Employee
}

sealed trait Team {
  def name: String
}

object Team {
  final case class FullTeam(name: String, members: List[Employee]) extends Team
  final case class OnlyDevelopersTeam(name: String, members: List[IndividualContributor]) extends Team
}

def teamSalaries(team: Team): Double = team match {
  case Team.FullTeam => ???
  case Team.OnlyDevelopersTeam => ???
}

def teamLinesOfCode(team: Team): Option[Double] = team match {
  case Team.OnlyDevelopersTeam => Some(???)
  case _ => None
}
```

But this just moves something that could have been checked by the compiler into the runtime, and imposes managing an unnecessary `Option`. But, if the data is dynamic and you can not know at compile time which team you have then this is a good *(best?)* option.

### A typeclass

```
trait HasSalary[T] {
  def salary(t: T): Double
}

trait HasLinesOfCode[T] {
  def linesOfCode(t: T): Double
}

sealed trait Employee {
  def salary: Double
}
object Employee {
  final case class IndividualContributor(salary: Double, linesOfCode: Int) extends Employee
  final case class Manager(salary: Double, reports: List[Employee]) extends Employee

  implicit EmployeeHasSalary: HasSalary[Employee] = (employee: Employee) => employee.salary
  implicit IndividualContributorHasLinesOfCode: HasLinesOfCode[IndividualContributor] = (employee: IndividualContributor) => employee.linesOfCode
}

final case class Team[+T](name: String, members: List[T])

def teamSalaries[T : HasSalary](team: Team[T]): Double = ???
def teamLinesOfCode[T : HasLinesOfCode](team: Team[T]): Double = ???
```

But this is probably too much boilerplate for nothing. However, if your abstractions are general enough, are implemented for many unrelated types and the type of the data can be determined at compile time then nothing beats the *flexibility* & *safety* of a **typeclass**.

Comment: (1/2) Thank you for all this detail! Regarding the ADT approach, so it looks like if you need to know at runtime what kind of team it is, due to type erasure my approach would require additional complexities with ClassTag to work on either Team[IndividualContributor] or Team[Manager]. Your approach with FullTeam and OnlyDevelopersTeam is much cleaner.

Comment: (2/2) Regarding the type class approach, some benefits are: Flexibility that other types which want to teamSalaries can provide their own impl of HasSalary. Unlike duck-typing, which is just based on happening to have a field called salary, here you are explicitly implementing HasSalary for your class. You can do similar with interfaces, but advantages of type classes over interfaces are described in this nice article I'm still reading https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2017/01/07/how_do_type_classes_differ_from_interfaces.html.

Comment: @allstar first of all, you are welcome :) second, yeah an **ADT** is pretty great for overcoming type erasure. Third, effectively **typeclasses** are a very powerful tool, but as with all tools, being the _"best"_ doesn't mean there won't be better alternatives; for example, if you know only `Employees` will have salary then `HasSalary` is just extra boilerplate for nothing, but when you need that flexibility the boilerplate feels insignificant over the advantages, and I personally love them.

Comment: just a minor hint: I dare say in your ADT example, it's always possible to calculate the teams salary. No need for option here.

Furthermore: do you really need to ADT the team? couldnt you leave the type paramter in `Team[T]` and add implicit type tags for the type of team members. you can later match on that withouth having to create an explicit ADT.

Comment: @Winson yeah I should fix the salaries example. The typetags alternative may be another one, that is the point of this answer to show that there are many alternatives _(I also forgot to mention structural types for example)_. However, I personally do not like **TypeTags**, I never could made use of them.

Comment: If following the ADT approach and having higher levels of nesting you would introduce more types at each level? For example, you have 2 types of Project, which are PlanningProject(teams: List[FullTeam]) and SoftwareProject(teams: OnlyDevelopersTeam). And now if you introduce BudgetingProject which should only have managers, you also introduce OnlyManagersTeam?

Comment: @allstar so again, the question is simply too broad. There are many approaches on how to design and all are _"valid"_ because all have trade-offs. You need both a good understanding of the problem and how it may evolve as well as some experience which those approaches to be able to decide which one is the _"best"_ for each case.

Answer (score 2):

I'll object a little to **@winson**'s answer :)

> You could probably do without the type bound. While it is possible to
> have a `Team[Int]`, nobody would do that and the bounds might complicate
> a lot of other type signatures that are related to a `Team` as e.g.
> method parameter, ...

It's worth noting that type bounds are not just to exclude something external like `Int` in this case. If you decide to refactor your code, either moving methods `teamSalaries` and `teamLinesOfCode` inside the case class `Team`

```
case class Team[T <: Employee](name: String, members: List[T]) {
  def salaries = members.map(_.salary).sum
  def linesOfCode(implicit ev: T <:< IndividualContributor) = 
    members.map(_.linesOfCode).sum
}
```

or defining them as extension methods

```
implicit class TeamOps[T <: Employee](val team: Team[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def salaries = team.members.map(_.salary).sum
  def linesOfCode(implicit ev: T <:< IndividualContributor) = 
    team.members.map(_.linesOfCode).sum
}
```

then without upper bounds the code will not compile.

Comment: Thank you Dymtro! When you're creating functions  on your own classes, vs extending some code you don't control, is there an advantage to the extension methods approach?

Comment: @allstar In this specific case currently I can't see advantages. But generally, yes, there can be advantages. Suppose you add some method `def foo(t: T, f: SomeType => T): SomeType1 = ???` into the class `Team[T]`. If you make the class covariant this will not compile. So if you make `Team` covariant you'll have either to fix the signature `def foo[T1 >: T](t: T1, f: SomeType => T1): SomeType1 = ???` or add the original `foo` as an extension method.

Comment: @allstar For example, for this reason methods for `HList` (`::[+H, +T]` is covariant) are added as extension methods https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala#L25-L26

Comment: that's why I added to "share my experience". Your solution is obviously the correct one, but given the example, which only modeled a simple case class I just pointed out that the bounds may complicate a lot of whatever is building on them. At some point my codebase started to use a lot of `foo[_ <: Employee]` etc. I found that if its possible - delay the usage of type bounds as long as possible. you may not need them and it keeps your codebase simpler.

Comment: @winson Well, this relates to every feature in a language with type system. Either you use a feature and then sometimes this makes things harder because you have to convince the compiler that you're allowed to make some operations but at the same time the compiler catches your mistakes if you made them and didn't notice that. Or you don't use a feature and this makes things easier but you can make mistakes and compiler will not help. This is a trade-off.

Comment: @winson If `T <: Employee` is your business logic but you don't let the compiler know about that this means you hide some business-logic info from the compiler and it can't help. Either you prefer to have troubles with convincing the compiler or you prefer to have troubles with debugging.

Comment: I agree Dmytro, I just wanted to give a different perspective for OP. I struggled a lot with existential types and at some point, if used in generic type parameters it got messy real quick. DDD is about readability also. I will leave this discussion now. You are right in general of course.

Answer (score 1):

If I may share my experience here:

You could probably do without the type bound. While it is possible to have a `Team[Int]`, nobody would do that and the bounds might complicate a lot of other type signatures that are related to a `Team` as e.g. method parameter, ...

I advise you however, as Luis Miguel commented, to make `Team` covariant.

One side related note: dependent on your domain you might implement `teamSalaries` as `totalSalary` method on `Team`. If your domain experts talk about "total salary of a team" in this context it could make sense. DDD is about modeling and expressiveness (ubiquitous language)

Comment: I added my answer as a minor counter-argument :)